# Globalize3 fallback to default translation if current locale unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, refinerycms

Using RefineryCMS, does anyone know if there's a way to fallback to the default front-end locale if the current locale is unavailable?

I have pages in English, but when visiting the version for another locale, say /fr, if it doesn't have a translation it's blank but I'd like the English to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. The new beta version (0.2.0beta3) of globalize3 has an config option to enable fallbacks.